# AS3 - Get reference of instance who called a function

Tags: actionscript-3, function, class, flash, call

I have two classes, "player" and "Stickman", "player" extends "Stickman".
The class "Stickman" contains functions that all characters will have in the game such as moving and handling animations (all use the same animations) while the "player" class contains player-exclusive actions.
When I call an action from a player instance that is inherited from the "Stickman" base class, how do I correctly point (from the stickman base class) to that player instance that called the function?

For example, to handle running animations

Trigger code in player.as:

```
moveType("running");
```

moveType function in Stickman.as:

```
public function moveType(type:String):void{
    this.gotoAndPlay("running");
    trace("testing");
}
```

To start playing frame with frame label "running" inside the player object (which is an extend of Stickman). I know ***this*** doesn't work, so I would like to replace ***this*** with something that would point to the caller of the function (i.e. the player object).The trace statement still runs so there (should) be no problem with the linkage. Is there a way to do this without passing the childId of the player object?

Comment: Does Stickman inherit from MovieClip or does it contain a reference to a MovieClip within it that contains the timeline?

Comment: Inherited from a MovieClip that contains the timeline itself... I think. It's the AS Class Linkage of the Movieclip that contains the timeline containing the animations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all about so called `inheritance`. Player **IS** actually a `Stickman`. So when you call `moveType` you are calling it **ON** `Player` object. If you don't have such function inside it, it looks up in the inheritance chain, and finds it inside `Stickman`.

Inheritance is one-directional. Which means that `Player` knows all methods of `Stickman`, but the opposite is not true - `Stickman` works only by itself and does not know who extended it and who not.

That said - you must use the `Player` class as a starting point and decide what to do from there on.

Long story short - you need to *override* the function from `Stickman` into `Player` and then decide what to do and what not. Example:

`Stickman`:

```
public function move(type:String):void {
    this.gotoAndPlay(type); // regular workflow for reach Stickman
}
```

`Player`:

```
override public function move(type:String):void {
    if (type == 'player_specific') {
        this.gotoAndPlay('frameAvailableOnlyForPlayerClip');
        // maybe something else, player specific, like play sound or smth else
    } else {
        super.move(type); // calls whatever is inside Stickman::move
    }
}
```

Remember - `this` is always the very same object that you are calling the function for. But you can decide if you want something specific (player case) or you want the very usual flow. `super.move` will call what's in the parent class.

Inheritance is very important and I cheer you for deciding to use it! With a little more practice you will master it!

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware of the one-directional property of inheritance.

Comment: Think of it as a real-life categorization: You are *human*. You are a male (for example). You do whatever a regular *human* does, but you are a little bit more categorized. You are different from *female*, which is again a *human* being. If you just say *human*, you won't be able to determine the gender, right? The exact same way `Stickman` does not bring any info about `Player`.